# How To Send HTML Attachment With Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, email, email-attachments

I'm trying to create POS Android Application, I added feature that after a order submitted the app send the order invoice with email to the customer.

My problem is how to create this invoice with unfixed number of data presented in the invoice so I can send it through email?.

Similar To This One:
[image]

by the way I'm using java email API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/) to use email templating.